# How do I convert canvas to binary format?

Tags: javascript

I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert HTML to an image.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('body')).then((canvas) => {
    let jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    let pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // PNG is the default
    let base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').split(';base64,')[1];
});
```

My goal is to "when a user submits a form, then capture the current page and convert it to canvas (image)" So that I can store that image in a MySQL database in blob format.
Currently, I am able to convert captured image in `base64 string`. But then I need to convert `base64 string` into `blob` (binary). So that I am able to store blob in MySQL.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Didn't you check for "creating blob from base64" ? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, the link you shared is the conversion of `base64 to blob`. I am getting `blob` but then how can I store that generated blob object to my database. (I am using BLOB in MySQL to store images)

Comment: Can you please see my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472403/how-to-store-blob-object-to-mysql-database?noredirect=1#comment124574222_70472403

Comment: My guess would be to use Blob.text() , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text

Comment: Tried but didn't success

Comment: What does that mean? Do you have an error message? How far did you go?