# How to store blob object to mySql database?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am generating blob -

```
let blob = new Blob([document.querySelector("body").outerHTML], {type: 'image/png'});
```

Output of above code in my case is -
[image]

Now from here I want to store the generated blob to MySQL database.
I am using BLOB format in MySQL to store images.
How to store generated blob object to MySQL ?

**Edit 1 :**
I can see my image at the bottom of the page.

```
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = blobUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

But I don't know how to store that image as BLOB in MySQL.
Any help or any suggestion ?

**Edit 2 :**
I am using table structre as -

```
CREATE TABLE images(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    image_data LONGBLOB,
    image_title CHAR(50),
    size CHAR(50)
);
```

But what should I pass in image_data ? I just have a Blob object generated by JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you share your attempts, it's easier to see where your code is going wrong

Comment: Please see my Edit 1

Comment: Just store as binary?

Comment: Your edited code does not contain any attempt to store anything in the database, that's why I've asked. How do you store the rest of your data?

Comment: OP didn't mention about the server-side code which require in order to connect with the database to perform the query.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using `INSERT INTO` method to store in db. but in image attribute what should I pass ?

Comment: Please share your attempts. Add them to your question by editing it.

Comment: @NicoHaase Please see my edit 2.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal Also post your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the data into `LONGBLOB` type.

Send your image data and image title using `AJAX`

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('title', 'Enter title here');
data.append('image', blob);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
});
```

Then create table into `database`

```
CREATE TABLE images(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    image_data LONGBLOB,
    image_title CHAR(50)
);
```

Now store your data into variable and `insert` into created `database`

upload.php

```
$image_data = $_POST['image'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO images(image_data,image_title)
        VALUES('$title','file_get_contents($image_data)')";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please share more details. I don't think that a table definition alone helps the OP to store the data

Comment: Please see my edit 2

Comment: The second edit does not make any sense. `mysql_query`  was removed from PHP years ago, also the `INSERT`  query is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection and should never be used like that. Also, the query inserts the raw string `file_get_contents` to the database, and not the content of any file